# Control flow not type-narrowing with union tuple?

Tags: typescript, types, tuples, type-narrowing

I have an issue with tuples:

```js
export async function redirectIf(
  nextCookies: NextApiRequestCookies,
  options: { notAuth: PagePath },
): Promise<[Redirect, undefined] | [undefined, UserDto]>;
```

It is not aware that the `user` exists if `redirect` does not:

[image: VSCode view of the type]

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzaBeKBvKBbeKAXFPMAE4CWAdilAL4DcAUE0vCFQMZQBmArl2AUA9lSgALCABspwgBQBKYgAUyw3BXgQAPAG04iVBAA0UAQBMIPahHMBdKAB8oui1ZvnTB5GjsA+ZlZ2Ll4BTiFRCWlZRRU1DS09byMnMypLaypbLwQfaGc3TNt-bCYoKDIIYD4yMVd09yzPbDwCYgByAAkAUQBNdvo7ZjoWOTYObkUodD9S8s5RUhckUwAjB0wkAHckCmAomXkFQPKKHigxhTnyiqqaqmZykbKoAHpXknFhPilzKAgAB6aYAAQheCyo8GEUggADpZCg5KtYfgUMcmHQFIoGEA)

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I took the liberty to edit your question title.

Comment: Not at all, that is even better! Thank you, @msanford!

Comment: It was an interesting question using some nice TS features, I was curious myself. Glad you found an answer (and came back here to post it)! If you're curious, [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010) is where control-flow type-narrowing was introduced.

Comment: Thank you for the reference and to TypeScript's big brain teams for their hard work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Gerrit0#7591 on the [TypeScript Community](https://discord.gg/typescript) discord server who answered:

---

TypeScript does not track narrowing across separate variables. If you have:

```
const x: [true, string] | [false, Error] = ...
```

And check the first element of the tuple, then TS can narrow down the type:

```
if (x[0]) {
  // TS knows x[1] is a string
}
```

But if you destructure first, then you have two (as far as TS knows) totally unrelated variables.

```
const [isStr, val] = x
if (isStr) {
   // val is string | Error, not string
}
```

There's no real workaround to this besides not destructuring, or doing destructuring after having narrowed the type sufficiently.

```
if (x[0]) {
  const val = x[1] // val: string
}
```

---

Comment: (Don't forget to come back later and mark this as the accepted answer.)

Comment: For sure, will do.