# How do I create tuple types that depend on each other in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, tuples

I have the following function that allows me to handle async errors similar to Go.

```
type AsyncResults<ErrorType, DataType> = Promise<
    readonly [undefined, DataType] | readonly [ErrorType, undefined]
>;

const asyncHandler = <ErrorType, DataType>(
    asyncFunc: Promise<DataType>,
): AsyncResults<ErrorType, DataType> => {
    return asyncFunc
        .then((data: DataType) => [undefined, data] as const)
        .catch((error: ErrorType) =>
            Promise.resolve([error, undefined] as const),
        );
};
```

When I call it, I usually get error type to be 'unknown', which is ok, but my result type is always whatever is inferred union undefined

```
const [err, verifiedUser] = await asyncHandler(
        getPasswordVerifiedUser(db, {
            email,
            password,
        }),
    );
if (err) throw err
const user: VerifiedUser = {
   firstName: verifiedUser.firstName (TS complains that object may be undefined)
}
```

So verifiedUser above has inferred type 'Document | undefined'. Is there a way for TypeScript to know that if err is undefined then verifiedUser cannot be undefined (and vice versa)? I want that if I handle the err by throwing or returning, TS recognizes that verifiedUser can no longer be undefined.

Comment: Cheating a bit, you could use `if (!verifiedUser) throw err`, but this does of course not answer the type-system related question. :-)

Comment: I could, but I already throw an error in the getVerifiedUser function, which guarantees that it returns a Document. I suppose what I want to do is impossible as someone said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is impossible. TypeScript does not make any difference between a resolution and a rejection. This is how `reject` and `resolve` are being typed:

```
reject<T = never>(reason?: any): Promise<T>;
resolve<T>(value: T | PromiseLike<T>): Promise<T>;
```

They both return `Promise<T>` so there is no possible way to narrow down a `Promise`'s return type based on the control-flow.

More information about this here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7588#issuecomment-199079907

**Edit:**

If you want to narrow the tuple type union, just don't destructure it:

```
// Considering ErrorType is number and DataType is { firstName: string }

const result = await asyncHandler<number, { firstName: string }>(
    getPasswordVerifiedUser<{ firstName: string }>(),
);

if (result[0] !== undefined) throw result[0]

const user = {
    firstName: result[1].firstName // works
}
```

It's the only solution that I found and it seems to be confirmed here: [Control flow not type-narrowing with union tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68855843/control-flow-not-type-narrowing-with-union-tuple)

Comment: Just to clarify, neither are rejected. Both are resolved to either [undefined, DataType] or [ErrorType, undefined]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: No problem. When I try this, it says result is "readonly [undefined, Document] | readonly [unknown, undefined]" and I still have to handle it as above. Edit: This is likely because error is unknown in my case, TS can't narrow it down this way. When I type error as Error interface and verifiedUser as Document explicitly, then use your method it works. It's definitely good to know for future use cases, but for readability I will just stick to destructuring and handle undefined results appropriately. Thanks alot!

Comment: Really? I tested it and it worked with TypeScript 4.5, are you using an older version?

Comment: I edited my previous comment. Error being unknown was a problem. Once it's something specific it works. Thanks!